# Access Denied in deploy SharePoint Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, 2013, access-denied, app

I'm trying to build a sharepoint app with type sharepoint hosted app, i'm following the instructions of msdn site:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179923(v=office.15).aspx#SP15appdevonprem_bk_configure

In my case, i have developer site:

```
http://developer
```

I already configured the app url:
developer.mybussines.local

In hosts is already pointed for my local developer site, too is already configured my application pool, and exceptions in my browsers, but when i deploy my app, it no have problem, but when i access the app in my developer site, show me access denied.

I've already changed for the developer site, for my sharepoint site, but nothing happens, I followed the article of msdn correctly and nothing.

Tks

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments on the site, step 6 which adds the user to the account, and sets the proper app pools is incorrect. I'd investigate that avenue and make sure the permissions are properly set to match that user account.

```
$account= Get-SPManagedAccount "domain\user"

$appPoolSubSvc= New-SPServiceApplicationPool -Name SettingsServiceAppPool -Account $account

$appPoolAppSvc= New-SPServiceApplicationPool -Name AppServiceAppPool -Account $account

$appSubSvc= New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplication –ApplicationPool $appPoolSubSvc –Name SettingsServiceApp –DatabaseName SettingsServiceDB 

$proxySubSvc= New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplicationProxy –ServiceApplication $appSubSvc

$appAppSvc= New-SPAppManagementServiceApplication -ApplicationPool $appPoolAppSvc -Name AppServiceApp -DatabaseName AppServiceDB

$proxyAppSvc= New-SPAppManagementServiceApplicationProxy -ServiceApplication $appAppSvc
```

Answer (score 0):

Just insert the `ApplicationPool` argument manually instead of as a variable and it should work.

I have tried it and it works for me.

Comment: Can you please provide more details regarding how to do that?